# How to check if window exists in Python3.x on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, api, python-3.x

I am currently trying to figure out how I can access a sort of "linux api" through Python on Linux. My problem is that I keep wanting to do things the autoit way on windows so i'm trying to not only grasp the new language, but also the OS.

Basically my code will be something like this:

```
while (1)
if winexists("windowname") = 1 then
  kill(pid)
endif
wend
```

doing this through the windows API or through autoit directly is something i can do, but i'm not sure how to approach this in linux. and i'm not finding too many relevent search results on google. I'm not looking for someone to code for me, just need to get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use external programs' (like `wmctrl`) output using [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess

def winexists(target):
    for line in subprocess.check_output(['wmctrl', '-l']).splitlines():
        window_name = line.split(None, 3)[-1].decode()
        if window_name == target:
            return True
    return False
```

See [Related question in superuser.com - Get a list of open windows in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/176754/get-a-list-of-open-windows-in-linux).